# What is the 'WebsiteGetObject' operation in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm seeing a large amount of `WebsiteGetObject` operations appearing relatively sporadically in the cost explorer of one of our apps. I'm assuming it's distinct from `GetObject` but can find no mention of it in the API docs, Google or on searching this site.

[image: Cost explorer showing WebsiteGetObject appearing]

Does anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These would be requests through the [static hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) endpoint for the bucket, rather than accessing the bucket directly.